# spresenseのsecure通信(https)サンプルでエラーが発生する．

Tags: spresense

spresense＋LTE拡張ボードにて，
サンプルプログラム「LteHttpsSecureClient」を実行したところ，
下記のエラーが発生しました．

```
Starting secure HTTP client.
attach succeeded.
2022/02/15 17:10:05
making GET request
ERROR: mbedtls_x509_crt_parse() error : -0x2800
ERROR:LTETLSClient:216 not available
ERROR:LTETLSClient:216 not available
...

ERROR:LTETLSClient:216 not available
ERROR:LTETLSClient:216 not available
Status code: -2
Response: 
Wait five seconds
making POST request
ERROR: mbedtls_x509_crt_parse() error : -0x2800
```

CAの取得につきましては，公式サイト(下記URL)を参考にしております．
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#lte_howtoexport_cert

エラーの原因・解決方法等ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご提示のエラーログを見る限り証明書(CA)ファイルのParseに失敗しているようですね。
おそらく、証明書のダウンロードの際「Amazon Root CA」の証明書をダウンロードできていないと思われます。

私も一回間違って "httpbin.org" タブの中の証明書をダウンロードしてしまい、全く同じエラーに遭遇しました。
証明書のダウンロードの際 "Amazon Root CA 1" タブの中の証明書をダウンロードしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

私も調べたことがありますので、参考までに補足したいと思います。

参照されているガイドの例はfirefoxのケースでの説明だと思います。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#lte_howtoexport_cert

Windowsの他のブラウザ（Chrome,Edge）ケースだと、ブラウザで証明書をエクスポートする場合は、Wizardの選択時にPEM形式である"Base 64 encoded X.509 (.CER)(S)"の形式で落とす必要があります。